# Left join symfony2 using doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

i have two table non related  i would like to do INNER JOIN to get information from this result to show it on my twig ,i tried to do a simple join column

```
 $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        $classified = $em->createQueryBuilder()
                    ->select('fp')
                    ->from('BlogBundle:classified', 'fp')
                    ->innerJoin('fp.region', 'p')
                    ->andWhere('fp.region_id = p.region_id')
                    ->addOrderBy('fp.classifiedaddeddate', 'DESC')
                    ->getQuery()
                    ->getResult();
        return $this->render('BlogBundle:Page:index.html.twig', array(
            'classified' => $classified
        ));
```

i have two table `classified` and `region` 
in my class classified i have an  attribut region_id i would like to get the information from the table region,So i have to get at final an element with all attribut of classified and the all attribut of region
any idea please ?

Comment: Does it work? Does it give you an error message?

Comment: no it doesn't work when i try to show an attribut from my class region i have an error msg this attribute does not exist

Comment: Maybe you should define a relation in Doctrine before joining the second table.

Comment: Cannot you change your _region_id_ attribute to _region_, with the proper Doctrine annotation to explicitly define the relation ? You will then be able to get your Region entity from the Classified one automatically.

Comment: Try to replace `->innerJoin('fp.region', 'p') 
                    ->andWhere('fp.region_id = p.region_id')` by `->innerJoin('BlogBundle:region', 'p', 'WITH', 'fp.region_id = p.region_id')`. It should make a correct join, but I'm not sure you'll get a Region entity object with this.

Comment: i tried it but it's the same problem